# Using view firebird with filter by role

Tags: delphi, view, firebird, user-roles, firebird2.5

I have table `tbl_projects` with a field `"role"`. I want to use this field as parameter to filter data that each user have access. Example: I am employee from HR(my role) and I can't see projects from IT(other role).

My application use OSAuth. How can I build a view in firebird that filter the data based in all roles?

Example: This view filter only 'HR' role. I need filter for all roles.

```
CREATE OR ALTER VIEW HR_PROJECTS_VIEW(
    (_other_fields_)
    "ROLE")
AS
select
    P.(_other_fields_)
    P.ROLE
from 
    TBL_PROJECTS P
where 
    P.ROLE = 'HR';
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`CURRENT_ROLE`](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/reference_material/html/langrefupd25-current_role.html) context variable:

```
CREATE OR ALTER VIEW HR_PROJECTS_VIEW(
...
where 
    P.ROLE = CURRENT_ROLE;
```